# D3: How to detect the end of the .each()

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, dynamic-arrays

In D3.js, I am traversing through data using the following method:

```
elem.allDataRows.each(function(d, i) {
    elem.checkboxMemory[i] = {
        id: d.key,
        isChecked: d.isChecked
    };
});
```

Since this process is asynchronous, I need to be able to determine when the loop process is complete.

Is their any way in D3 that can I detect the end of the .each()? Not for every interval, but the entire process.

Just for the record, **elem.allDataRows** is an array.

Thank you!

Comment: `each` is synchronous

Comment: Whoops. So it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to check value of the index *i*:

```
function(d, i) {
    if (i == elem.allDataRows.length - 1){
        // last element
    }
    elem.checkboxMemory[i] = {
        id: d.key,
        isChecked: d.isChecked
    };
}
```

Comment: This was similar to what I was leaning AFTER I had posted this question, but you basically got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`each` is synchronous.

```js
d3.selectAll('div').each(function() {
 log(d3.select(this).text()); 
});

log('done');

function log(text) {
   var d = document.createElement('pre');
    d.innerHTML = 'log: ' + text;
   document.getElementById('output').appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>

<output id="output"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would start out by saying that `.each` is in fact **synchronous**. So if all you want to do is execute code after it has finished then you can do this on the line following your `.each` call.

If you are trying to identify the last item in your collection during the `.each` loop so you can apply special logic then you will want to compare the current index to the length of your jquery object. See my example below.

```
var lastIndex = elem.allDataRows.length - 1;
elem.allDataRows.each(function(d, i) {
    if (i == lastIndex) {
        // Do something cool here!
    }

    elem.checkboxMemory[i] = {
        id: d.key,
        isChecked: d.isChecked
    };
});
```

Comment: This was similar to what I was leaning AFTER I had posted this question, but you basically got it. Thank you!